# android twitter app : suspended (exception( Twitter Exception))

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter

I wanted to create a simple twitter update app android. I found at http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/69.html. 
Here is the code MyTwitter.Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;

public class MyTwitter extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    static final String TAG = "MyTwitter";

    Twitter twitter;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    Button buttonUpdate;
    Button buttonPrefs;
    EditText textStatus;



    @Override
    public void onClick(View src) 
    {

      String status = textStatus.getText().toString();

      Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on "+ status);

      // Toast
      Toast.makeText(this, textStatus.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      // set twitter status 
      twitter.setStatus(status);

      //reset status string
      textStatus.setText("");
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find views by id
        buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        textStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

        // Add listener
        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Initialize twitter
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String username = prefs.getString("username", "n/a");
        String password = prefs.getString("password", "n/a");
        if (username != null && password != null){
          twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
        }


    }

    @Override
    // when the menu button is pressed another layout is shown. that is menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
    }

    // Called when menu item is selected //
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

      switch(item.getItemId()){

      case R.id.menuPrefs:
        // Launch Prefs activity
        Intent i = new Intent(MyTwitter.this, Prefs.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "MenuPrefs starting Prefs");
        Toast.makeText(MyTwitter.this, textStatus.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

      }    
      return true;
    }
}
```

and the other one is Prefs.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
  }

}
```

here is the main layout xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <TextView android:text="@string/labelWhatsHappening" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="30sp" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textStatus"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textColorHint="#E6E6E6"
        android:textColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:maxLength="160"
        android:hint="@string/hintStatus"
        android:background="@color/transparentBlue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:minLines="4"></EditText>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
        android:text="@string/labelUpdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click at the update button. It force closed, and I got the following error :

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception TwitterException))  
    URLConnectionHttpClient.post(String, Map, boolean) line: 279    
    Twitter.updateStatus(String, Number) line: 2471 
    Twitter.updateStatus(String) line: 2411 
    Twitter.setStatus(String) line: 2183    
    MyTwitter.onClick(View) line: 45    
    Button(View).performClick() line: 2485  
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 9080  
    ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Does it has something to do with the TwitterException? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quick review, you will need to make a call to `setAuthentication`.

I reviewed the stack trace, Googled "URLConnectionHttpClient.post(String, Map, boolean) line: 279"

Got to 
http://code.google.com/p/andriod-mytwitter/source/browse/JTwitter/src/winterwell/jtwitter/URLConnectionHttpClient.java?spec=svn39&r=39

Read the code then came to the above conclusion on the basis that it appears you haven't called `setAuthentication`.

You're nearly there, keep at it!